# When Android device connect to internet do operations in background or just show a message

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

i want to show a message dialog under these circumstances when device connect to **internet** , and app should be not runnig curruntly

Comment: I would like to advise you to be more precise about your question. Also, what effort have you done so far? Please show relevant code, other search results you've tried, etc. Also, please read this guide before posting a question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You can use a service to check constantly if the device is connected to the internet.

To show a message from a service you can either use a `Toast` or display a `Dialog`, which requires this permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
```

However, I would never want an app on my device, that does a) constantly check for connection, so is using RAM and data all the time and b) has the permission to display over all other apps.